# No puedo desocupar en mi lista de laboratorios

Tags: c#, textarea

El programa que tenemos aquí está en C#. Hay dos listas, uno de maestros y uno de laboratorios; existen 8 laboratorios y cuando se imprime pues nuestro número de este y que está libre (Available). Hay dos métodos que sin ocupar y desocupar, estos funcionan que cuando quieras de ejemplo ocupar un laboratorio, ingresas el número del mismo, luego la ID del usuario que ocupará el laboratorio (osea el maestro), su contraseña y listo, ahora se imprimirá denuevo la lista de laboratorios dejando ver qué donde decía "Disponible" ahora dice el nombre del maestro. Así debería pasar igual con el método que sirve para desar, esta vez quitando el nombre del maestro y dejando nuevamente este para que diga "Available", el problema viene a ser que no se como debería codificar se el método.

Intente antes reutilizar el código que está dentro del método "Ocuppy" pero cambiando cosas. Aún con eso, no logré darme una idea de que modificar para que dé el resultado que deseo, así que lo borre y por eso no lo puse en el código que mostraré ahora. Sí es posible, me gustaría que me ayudesen a concretar esta parte del código.

**Código:**

````
app.AddTeacher(nuevo Profesor("JALU1","Jonathan","maestro123"));

app.AddTeacher(nuevo Profesor("GAGP1","Geovany","maestro123"));

app.AddTeacher(nuevo Profesor("AMKC","Ángel","maestro123"));

app.AddTeacher(nuevo Profesor("DACQ","David","maestro123"));

id de cadena, contraseña;

laboratorio int;

bool continuar mientras = verdadero;

mientras (continuar mientras)

{

Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");

Console.WriteLine("Are you going to occupy or vacate a laboratory? (1: Occupy | 2: Vacate)");

int respuesta = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()!);

if(respuesta == 1)

{

    app.ShowTeachers();

    app.PrintLabs();

    Console.Write("Enter the laboratory: ");

    laboratory = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()!);

    Console.Write("Enter the ID: ");

    id = Console.ReadLine()!;

    Console.Write("Enter the password: ");

    password = Console.ReadLine()!;

    app.Occupy(laboratory,id,password);

    app.PrintLabs();

}

else

{

    app.ShowTeachers();

    app.PrintLabs();

    Console.Write("Enter the laboratory: ");

    laboratory = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()!);

    Console.Write("Enter the ID: ");

    id = Console.ReadLine()!;

    Console.Write("Enter the password: ");

    password = Console.ReadLine()!;

    app.Vacate(laboratory,id,password);

    app.PrintLabs();

}

Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------");

Console.WriteLine("Would you like to make more changes to the program? (Yes/No)");

string ExitProgram = Console.ReadLine()!;

if(ExitProgram == "Yes" || ExitProgram == "yes")

{

    continueWhile = true;

}

else

{

    continueWhile = false;

}
}

profesor de la clase

{

public string id, name, password;

public Teacher(string id, string name, string password)

{

    this.id = id;

    this.name = name;

    this.password = password;

}
}

laboratorio de clase

{

public string? nameTeacher;

public Laboratory(string nameTeacher, string password)

{

    this.nameTeacher = nameTeacher;

}
}

aplicación de clase

{

List<Laboratory?> laboratorys = new List<Laboratory?>(new Laboratory[8]);

List<Teacher> teachers = new List<Teacher>();

public void AddTeacher(Teacher teacher)

{

    int index = teachers.FindIndex(x => x.name == teacher.name);

    if(index != -1)

    {

        Console.WriteLine("The teacher already exists");

    }

    else

    {

        teachers.Add(teacher);

    }

}

public void RemoveTeacher(string name)

{

    int index = teachers.FindIndex(x => x.name == name);

    Teacher teacher = teachers[index];

    if(name == teacher.name)

    {

        teachers.Remove(teacher);

    }

    else

    {

        Console.WriteLine("The teacher you want to delete does not exist");

    }

}

public void PrintLabs()

{

    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------");

    Console.WriteLine("                         LABORATORYS                          ");

    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------");

    int index = 1;

    foreach(Laboratory PrintLaboratory in laboratorys)

    {

        Console.WriteLine("Laboratory {0}: {1}", index, (PrintLaboratory?.nameTeacher ?? "Available"));

        index ++;

    }

    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------");

}

public void ShowTeachers()

{

    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------");

    Console.WriteLine("                           TEACHERS                           ");

    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------");

    foreach(Teacher teachersList in teachers)

    {

        Console.WriteLine("ID: {0} - Name: {1} - Password: {2}",teachersList.id,teachersList.name,teachersList.password);

    }

}

public void Occupy(int numLaboratory, string id, string password)

{

    numLaboratory--;

    Teacher? teacher = teachers.Find(x => x.id == id);

    if(teacher == null)

    {

        Console.WriteLine("ID incorrect");

    }

    else if(laboratorys[numLaboratory] == null)

    {

        if(teacher?.password == password)

        {

            laboratorys[numLaboratory] = new Laboratory(teacher.name,teacher.password);

        }

        else

        {

            Console.WriteLine("Password incorrect");

        }

    }

}

public void Vacate(int numLaboratory, string id, string password)

{

}
}```
````

Comment: Primero de todo, el código ha de ser reproducible(copiar pegar ), segundo si es el caso que es reproducible, pero requiere de librerías o que .net usas para que podamos darte la mejor solución posible. Tercero evita usar el corrector en el codigo (ej mientras( continuar mientras))

Comment: Nosotros podemos arreglar el codigo pero puede llegar el caso que al arreglarlo no produzca el error, o produzca un error distinto